# Flatten list of lists vertically in Python

Tags: python

### Input

```
a = [
        [1, 'abc', '123'],
        [1, 'def', '456'],
        [2, 'ghi', '789'],
        [2, 'jkl', '012'],
        [2, 'mno', '345'],
        [3, 'pqr', '678']
    ]
```

What is the best way to achieve the desired output below? Keeping in mind that the input list `a` is going to be huge (~100K).

### Output

```
a = [
        [1, 'abc;def', '123;456'],
        [2, 'ghi;jkl;mno', '789;012;345'],
        [3, 'pqr', '678']
    ]
```

Note:

- Elements are grouped based on Column1.
- Order of elements is not important (can be in any order).
- Any subsequent columns are then concatenated by a separator `;`.
- Barring the first column, all other columns are string fields.

Comment: The elements of second and third columns must be in the order the are in `a` ?

Comment: Thanks for raising this up. Order is not important. I will update the question..

Comment: Is the incoming list sorted by first column?

Comment: Yes the incoming list will be sorted by default. But the output doesn't need to be sorted though.

Comment: So, have you made even the slightest attempt to solve this yourself? Define "best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about performance, but I might use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and do something like [edited to make each sublist one flat list]:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [[k] + [';'.join(v) for v in zip(*g)[1:]] for k,g in groupby(a, itemgetter(0))]
[[1, 'abc;def', '123;456'], [2, 'ghi;jkl;mno', '789;012;345'], [3, 'pqr', '678']]
```

This assumes that the list is contiguous in the first element of the sublists.  If not, then you'd need to replace the `groupby` by

```
groupby(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))
```

instead.

The above uses a few tricks:

1. `groupby`, which groups contiguous elements in an iterable by the value of the key function
2. `itemgetter`, which basically gets elements quickly: `itemgetter(0)` is basically a fast `lambda x: x[0]`
3. `zip(*g)`, which is a common idiom to transpose things by combining `zip` and `*` tuple unpacking: `zip(*([1,2],[3,4])) == [(1, 3), (2, 4)]`.  (In Python 2, anyway, in 3 you'd need to make it `list(zip(..))`.)

Comment: This answer is great but it doesn't actually produces the desired output. Barring the first column, other columns are in a list. They need to be distinct element.

Comment: If you can change the code to adapt to the output then I can accept this answer.

Comment: @PankajParashar: oops.  Easily fixed.

Comment: Yeah thanks...I figured out that...!

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [
        [1, 'abc', '123'],
        [1, 'def', '456'],
        [2, 'ghi', '789'],
        [2, 'jkl', '012'],
        [2, 'mno', '345'],
        [3, 'pqr', '678']
    ]

dd = defaultdict(lambda: [[], []])

for key, s0, s1 in a:
    dd[key][0].append(s0)
    dd[key][1].append(s1)

a = [[key, ';'.join(dd[key][0]), ';'.join(dd[key][1])] for key in dd]

for elem in a:
    print elem
```

Output:

```
[1, 'abc;def', '123;456']
[2, 'ghi;jkl;mno', '789;012;345']
[3, 'pqr', '678']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been able to get so far, if anyone could throw some pieces of code upon this piece of code, it'd be great:

```
a = [
        [1, 'abc', '123'],
        [1, 'def', '456'],
        [2, 'ghi', '789'],
        [2, 'jkl', '012'],
        [2, 'mno', '345'],
        [3, 'pqr', '678']
    ]
    count = 2
    index = 1
    prev_val = a[index][0]
    output = []
    first_ele = a[0]

while index < len(a)+1:
    if prev_val == count:
        output[first_ele][1] += ';' + a[index][1] + str(a[index][2])
    else:
        count += 1
        index += 1`
```